# jQuery appended template not updating

Tags: jquery, templates

I have a template that I append with few variables. The template doesn't update when fresh variables are passed into it. I tested with .empty() method on the template's div, but the result is an empty template instead of a fresh one. Will appreciate any help. My JS is:

```
function InLineLinks(formController, fieldController) 
{ 
  ...

  self.showServerErrorPopup = function(serverError)
  {        
    console.log("showServerErrorPopup serverError=", serverError);
    jQuery('body').appendTemplate('inline-links:servererror-popup',{            
        containerID:"servererror",            
        serverError:serverError
    });            
    self.popupServerError = jQuery('#servererror').popup({                    
        'beforePopupClose': self.beforeServerPopupClose,
        'afterPopupOpen' : self.afterServerPopupOpen,});

    jQuery('#servererror').popup('show');
    jQuery('#servererror').focus();  
  };
  self.beforeServerPopupClose = function(){
    console.log("beforeServerPopupClose");
    if(self.popupServerError)
    {     

        $('#servererror').empty();
        self.popupServerError = null;
    }               
  };
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by testing for the div existing, and removing it if so right before creating a new one:

```
self.showServerErrorPopup = function(serverError)
{        
    console.log("showServerErrorPopup serverError=", serverError);
    if($('#servererror').length)
    {
        $('#servererror').remove();
    }    
    jQuery('body').appendTemplate('inline-links:servererror-popup',{            
        containerID:"servererror",            
        serverError:serverError
    });            
    self.popupServerError = jQuery('#servererror').popup({                    
        'beforePopupClose': self.beforeServerPopupClose,
        'afterPopupOpen' : self.afterServerPopupOpen,});

    jQuery('#servererror').popup('show');
    jQuery('#servererror').focus(); 
}
```